# UTF8 behavior in asp.mvc6 with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, utf-8, dependency-injection

I have got a strange Problem with strings in an asp.net 5 application, using asp.mvc 6 and the build in dependency injection (this is my conclusion). In a controller, I return a custom class created from a class library injected into the controller. To demonstrate the problem, I created a Test Class.

```
public class TestContainer
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in a controller, I return a list of these containers; one is created in the controller, and one is created in a class library which is injected in the controller.

In the controller:

```
[Route("api/testmethod")]
public List<TestContainer> TestMethod()
{
    var testlocal = new TestContainer()
    { 
        Caption = "aouäöü some name"
    };

    var testdpi = _businessLogic.ReturnTestContainer();

    return new List<TestContainer>() {testlocal, testdpi};
}
```

In the injected library I use the following method to create the Testcontainer:

```
public TestContainer ReturnTestContainer()
{
    var test = new TestContainer()
    {
        Caption = "aouäöü some name",
    };

    return test;
}
```

Now the strange thing happens. If I debug the application, it looks as follows:

Images can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16918982/StackOverflow/utf8/local.PNG) and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16918982/StackOverflow/utf8/injected.PNG).

For the local generate class, it shows:

aouäöü some name

For the Caption property, but for the class generated by the injected class it shows:

aou��� some name

For the caption property and the output in the browser, it looks as follows:

[{"Caption":"aouäöü some name"},{"Caption":"aou��� some name"}]

I can´t explain this behavior to myself. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess, since MVC6 is still in beta, is that this behavior is most likely a bug and should be reported to the MVC team so it can be fixed before the official release. Or failing that, at least you might be able to get a reasonable explanation from them.

Comment: Do you know, how I can report this? I`am not so experienced with open source projects, but it would be great, if I can contribute to the MVC Project.

Comment: You can open an issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues) you just need to register with GitHub (for free) first and then you can post the issue there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have reported this issue under #2967.

Comment: Thank you for the edit (Wandering Fool). I'am working on my english.